# jersey rest issues

Tags: jersey

I always end up with the "The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes" error

I shouldn't even need anything other then jersey-bundle
but without it I get errors regarding the asm.jar

```
package akiraapps.jerseytest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    // This method is called if TEXT_PLAIN is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String sayPlainTextHello() {
        return "Hello Jersey";
    }

    // This method is called if XML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";
    }

    // This method is called if HTML is request
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHtmlHello() {
        return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"
                + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</body></h1>" + "</html> ";
    }


}
```

WEB.XML------

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>akiraapps.jerseytest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

[image: classpath]

ERROR LOG:

> Jun 16, 2011 11:54:03 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig
>   init INFO: Scanning for root resource
>   and provider classes in the packages: 
>   akiraapps.jerseytest.Hello Jun 16,
>   2011 11:54:03 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl
>   _initiate INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.7
>   05/20/2011 11:43 AM' Jun 16, 2011
>   11:54:03 AM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules
>    SEVERE: The ResourceConfig
>   instance does not contain any root
>   resource classes. Jun 16, 2011
>   11:54:03 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException:
>   The ResourceConfig instance does not
>   contain any root resource classes.    at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:167)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:773)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:764)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1189)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:813)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
>   Jun 16, 2011 11:54:03 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Allocate exception for
>   servlet Jersey REST Service
>   com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException:
>   The ResourceConfig instance does not
>   contain any root resource classes.    at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:167)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:773)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:764)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
>     at
>   com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1189)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:813)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: I right-clicked on my project->Java EE Tools->Update EAR Libraries.  and it seems to be working now.  can anyone explain that?

Comment: It seems that your server cannot find the .class files (and so the resources). Updating EAR as you said seems to have copied those file in the right place.

Comment: If that solved your problem, add it as an answer and click the checkmark so that others know this problem is solved.

Comment: i cant it was a comment on my own post.  i dont get that option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Owen,

> I right-clicked on my project->Java EE Tools->Update EAR Libraries.
>   and it seems to be working now.

Comment: @owen, I didn't test this answer. I just re-posted it on your behalf.

Comment: i see, thanks. i didnt do this myself because i wasnt sure it was the real answer.  in the end this was never answered and never operated as expected.  if you want you can just delete the whole thing.

Comment: @Owen, you can delete your own question. If you want me to delete this answer you will need to unmark it as accepted.

Comment: ya i dont know, it might serve to help someone else.  i guess ill leave it.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered similar problems after refactoring Jersey web resources so don't forget to clean and recompile your project.

Answer (score 1):

I face the similar problem and later solved it by changing .classes files path through following steps:

1. Go to project properties.
2. Select Java build path tab and then select source tab.
3. Change 'Default output folder' which was by default myproject/build/classes to
   myproject/WebContent/WEB-INF/classes.

Answer (score -1):

i also had to update the project on Maven,
right click in the project-> Maven -> Update the porject