# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException when creating a jersey service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, jersey

I am working on jersey web service. I was able to create an some service an it worked fine.

when i create this service **MClientManagerImpl** i am getting the below mentioned error.

the jersey is  Registering Spring bean, mClientManager, of type com.vxl.service.impl.MClientManagerImpl as a root resource class. I am not getting why jersey is registering this as a root resource class.

```
@Service("mClientManager")
@Path("/clientmanager")
public class MClientManagerImpl extends GenericManagerImpl<MClient, Long>
        implements MClientManager {
    MClientDao mClientDao;

    @Inject
    @Autowired
    public MClientManagerImpl(@InjectParam MClientDao mClientDao) {
        super(mClientDao);
        this.mClientDao = mClientDao;
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Path("/getclient")
    @Override
    public String getclient(String json) {
        System.out.println(json);
        return null;
    }
}


INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Oct 16, 2013 9:52:53 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  com.vxl.service
Oct 16, 2013 9:52:53 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class com.vxl.service.impl.FDefectManagerImpl
  class com.vxl.service.impl.FComponentCodeMetricManagerImpl
  class com.vxl.service.impl.DimTestCaseManagerImpl
  class com.vxl.service.impl.FProjectManagerImpl
  class com.vxl.service.impl.DimOrganizationManagerImpl
  class com.vxl.service.impl.DimRequirementManagerImpl
  class com.vxl.service.impl.FCodingBestPracticeViolationsManagerImpl
  class com.vxl.service.impl.DimDefectManagerImpl
  class com.vxl.service.impl.MSourceInstanceManagerImpl
  class com.vxl.service.impl.DimProjectManagerImpl
Oct 16, 2013 9:52:53 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
Oct 16, 2013 9:52:53 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet getContext
INFO: Using default applicationContext
Oct 16, 2013 9:52:53 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory registerSpringBeans
INFO: Registering Spring bean, mClientManager, of type com.vxl.service.impl.MClientManagerImpl as a root resource class
Oct 16, 2013 9:52:53 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8 06/24/2011 12:17 PM'
Oct 16, 2013 9:52:54 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet initiate
SEVERE: Exception occurred when intialization
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'mClientManager' must be of type [com.vxl.service.impl.MClientManagerImpl], but was actually of type [com.sun.proxy.$Proxy134]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1109)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.SpringComponentProviderFactory$SpringManagedComponentProvider.getInstance(SpringComponentProviderFactory.java:235)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.component.IoCResourceFactory$SingletonWrapper.init(IoCResourceFactory.java:178)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$10.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:584)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$10.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:581)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.getResourceComponentProvider(WebApplicationImpl.java:581)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiateResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiateResource(WebApplicationImpl.java:653)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:124)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
```

i Googled and i was not getting an answer please help me.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Inject
    @Autowired
    public MClientManagerImpl(@InjectParam MClientDao mClientDao) {
        super(mClientDao);
        this.mClientDao = mClientDao;
    }
```

This code is a root cause of your problem, you should rely completely on interface rather than autowiring a class please have a look at [this answer by Tomasz Nurkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375675/jersey-rest-issues?rq=1)

Comment: the link is taking to some other page please check that

Comment: you can check the stacktrace in my question i have implemented nearly 10 services by the same way and i was not getting any error. i think its something related to jersey its trying to  Registering Spring bean, mClientManager, of type com.vxl.service.impl.MClientManagerImpl as a root resource class. when i make the **MClientManagerImpl** as normal service its working fine. but i cant use it as a webservice